# JQuery slimbox rebind after ajax callback

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, slimbox

I'm having trouble rebinding slimbox2 after ajax content is loaded. I realize I need to rebind the function on the ajax load but I have no idea how to do that. I'm using this code to generate the external content.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.content_box').hide();
$('.sf-menuUP a').click(function(){
$('.content_box').fadeIn('slow');
});

var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
var href = $('.sf-menuUP li a').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
        var toLoad = hash+'.html #content';
        $('#content').load(toLoad)
    }                                           
});

$('.sf-menuUP li a').click(function(){

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
    $('#content').fadeOut('fast',loadContent);
    $('#load').remove();
    $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
    $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
    function loadContent() {
        $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#content').fadeIn('normal',hideLoader());
    }
    function hideLoader() {
        $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
    }
    return false;
});
```

});

I tried adding

```
    // AUTOLOAD CODE BLOCK (MAY BE CHANGED OR REMOVED)
jQuery(function($) {
    $("a[rel^='lightbox']").slimbox({/* Put custom options here */}, null, function(el) {
        return (this == el) || ((this.rel.length > 8) && (this.rel == el.rel));
    });
});
```

to the bottom of my script hoping that would just reload it. But no luck.  I've read livequery could work, but I don't know how/where/what to do with that.

I'm getting desperate.  Please anyone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a look at [liveQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) for you.  Here's what you'd need to do:

```
$("a[rel^='lightbox']").livequery(function(){ 
    $(this).slimbox({/* Put custom options here */}, null, function(el) {
            return (this == el) || ((this.rel.length > 8) && (this.rel == el.rel));
    }), function() {
        //remove slimbox? this is called when elements no longer match
    }
});
```

Comment: OMG THANKS SO MUCH! I've wasted hours trying to figure this out! YES YES YES!

Comment: Problem with slimbox is, that it will override the complete slimbox at that moment. The `$(this).slimbox` should be replaced by the selector of the complete query. Like: `$("a[rel^='lightbox']").slimbox`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem trying to reload slimbox.  And implementing livequery for slimbox broke the gallery function just as redonkeechong experienced.

But I found on the Slimbox forum that you can simply add it to the AJAX output.  So it'll look like...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a[rel^='lightbox']").slimbox({/* Put custom options here */}, null, function(el) {
                return (this == el) || ((this.rel.length > 8) && (this.rel == el.rel));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Or you can save it to a separate file and use the getScript method after your AJAX call...

`$.getScript('slimbox2/js/slimbox2.autoload.js')`

Answer (score 0):

Call me picky, but the next/previous functions don't work when the now  pops up. Can livequery rebind those as well?

Here's the code for slimbox

```
/*!
    Slimbox v2.02 - The ultimate lightweight Lightbox clone for jQuery
    (c) 2007-2009 Christophe Beyls <http://www.digitalia.be>
    MIT-style license.
*/

(function($) {

    // Global variables, accessible to Slimbox only
    var win = $(window), options, images, activeImage = -1, activeURL, prevImage, nextImage, compatibleOverlay, middle, centerWidth, centerHeight, ie6 = !window.XMLHttpRequest,
        operaFix = window.opera && (document.compatMode == "CSS1Compat") && ($.browser.version >= 9.3), documentElement = document.documentElement,

    // Preload images
    preload = {}, preloadPrev = new Image(), preloadNext = new Image(),

    // DOM elements
    overlay, center, image, sizer, prevLink, nextLink, bottomContainer, bottom, caption, number;

    /*
        Initialization
    */

    $(function() {
        // Append the Slimbox HTML code at the bottom of the document
        $("body").append(
            $([
                overlay = $('<div id="lbOverlay" />')[0],
                center = $('<div id="lbCenter" />')[0],
                bottomContainer = $('<div id="lbBottomContainer" />')[0]
            ]).css("display", "none")
        );

        image = $('<div id="lbImage" />').appendTo(center).append(
            sizer = $('<div style="position: relative;" />').append([
                prevLink = $('<a id="lbPrevLink" href="#" />').click(previous)[0],
                nextLink = $('<a id="lbNextLink" href="#" />').click(next)[0]
            ])[0]
        )[0];

        bottom = $('<div id="lbBottom" />').appendTo(bottomContainer).append([
            $('<a id="lbCloseLink" href="#" />').add(overlay).click(close)[0],
            caption = $('<div id="lbCaption" />')[0],
            number = $('<div id="lbNumber" />')[0],
            $('<div style="clear: both;" />')[0]
        ])[0];
    });


    /*
        API
    */

    // Open Slimbox with the specified parameters
    $.slimbox = function(_images, startImage, _options) {
        options = $.extend({
            loop: false,                // Allows to navigate between first and last images
            overlayOpacity: 0.8,            // 1 is opaque, 0 is completely transparent (change the color in the CSS file)
            overlayFadeDuration: 400,       // Duration of the overlay fade-in and fade-out animations (in milliseconds)
            resizeDuration: 400,            // Duration of each of the box resize animations (in milliseconds)
            resizeEasing: "swing",          // "swing" is jQuery's default easing
            initialWidth: 250,          // Initial width of the box (in pixels)
            initialHeight: 250,         // Initial height of the box (in pixels)
            imageFadeDuration: 400,         // Duration of the image fade-in animation (in milliseconds)
            captionAnimationDuration: 400,      // Duration of the caption animation (in milliseconds)
            counterText: "Image {x} of {y}",    // Translate or change as you wish, or set it to false to disable counter text for image groups
            closeKeys: [27, 88, 67],        // Array of keycodes to close Slimbox, default: Esc (27), 'x' (88), 'c' (67)
            previousKeys: [37, 80],         // Array of keycodes to navigate to the previous image, default: Left arrow (37), 'p' (80)
            nextKeys: [39, 78]          // Array of keycodes to navigate to the next image, default: Right arrow (39), 'n' (78)
        }, _options);

        // The function is called for a single image, with URL and Title as first two arguments
        if (typeof _images == "string") {
            _images = [[_images, startImage]];
            startImage = 0;
        }

        middle = win.scrollTop() + ((operaFix ? documentElement.clientHeight : win.height()) / 2);
        centerWidth = options.initialWidth;
        centerHeight = options.initialHeight;
        $(center).css({top: Math.max(0, middle - (centerHeight / 2)), width: centerWidth, height: centerHeight, marginLeft: -centerWidth/2}).show();
        compatibleOverlay = ie6 || (overlay.currentStyle && (overlay.currentStyle.position != "fixed"));
        if (compatibleOverlay) overlay.style.position = "absolute";
        $(overlay).css("opacity", options.overlayOpacity).fadeIn(options.overlayFadeDuration);
        position();
        setup(1);

        images = _images;
        options.loop = options.loop && (images.length > 1);
        return changeImage(startImage);
    };

    /*
        options:    Optional options object, see jQuery.slimbox()
        linkMapper: Optional function taking a link DOM element and an index as arguments and returning an array containing 2 elements:
                the image URL and the image caption (may contain HTML)
        linksFilter:    Optional function taking a link DOM element and an index as arguments and returning true if the element is part of
                the image collection that will be shown on click, false if not. "this" refers to the element that was clicked.
                This function must always return true when the DOM element argument is "this".
    */
    $.fn.slimbox = function(_options, linkMapper, linksFilter) {
        linkMapper = linkMapper || function(el) {
            return [el.href, el.title];
        };

        linksFilter = linksFilter || function() {
            return true;
        };

        var links = this;

        return links.unbind("click").click(function() {
            // Build the list of images that will be displayed
            var link = this, startIndex = 0, filteredLinks, i = 0, length;
            filteredLinks = $.grep(links, function(el, i) {
                return linksFilter.call(link, el, i);
            });

            // We cannot use jQuery.map() because it flattens the returned array
            for (length = filteredLinks.length; i < length; ++i) {
                if (filteredLinks[i] == link) startIndex = i;
                filteredLinks[i] = linkMapper(filteredLinks[i], i);
            }

            return $.slimbox(filteredLinks, startIndex, _options);
        });
    };


    /*
        Internal functions
    */

    function position() {
        var l = win.scrollLeft(), w = operaFix ? documentElement.clientWidth : win.width();
        $([center, bottomContainer]).css("left", l + (w / 2));
        if (compatibleOverlay) $(overlay).css({left: l, top: win.scrollTop(), width: w, height: win.height()});
    }

    function setup(open) {
        $("object").add(ie6 ? "select" : "embed").each(function(index, el) {
            if (open) $.data(el, "slimbox", el.style.visibility);
            el.style.visibility = open ? "hidden" : $.data(el, "slimbox");
        });
        var fn = open ? "bind" : "unbind";
        win[fn]("scroll resize", position);
        $(document)[fn]("keydown", keyDown);
    }

    function keyDown(event) {
        var code = event.keyCode, fn = $.inArray;
        // Prevent default keyboard action (like navigating inside the page)
        return (fn(code, options.closeKeys) >= 0) ? close()
            : (fn(code, options.nextKeys) >= 0) ? next()
            : (fn(code, options.previousKeys) >= 0) ? previous()
            : false;
    }

    function previous() {
        return changeImage(prevImage);
    }

    function next() {
        return changeImage(nextImage);
    }

    function changeImage(imageIndex) {
        if (imageIndex >= 0) {
            activeImage = imageIndex;
            activeURL = images[activeImage][0];
            prevImage = (activeImage || (options.loop ? images.length : 0)) - 1;
            nextImage = ((activeImage + 1) % images.length) || (options.loop ? 0 : -1);

            stop();
            center.className = "lbLoading";

            preload = new Image();
            preload.onload = animateBox;
            preload.src = activeURL;
        }

        return false;
    }

    function animateBox() {
        center.className = "";
        $(image).css({backgroundImage: "url(" + activeURL + ")", visibility: "hidden", display: ""});
        $(sizer).width(preload.width);
        $([sizer, prevLink, nextLink]).height(preload.height);

        $(caption).html(images[activeImage][1] || "");
        $(number).html((((images.length > 1) && options.counterText) || "").replace(/{x}/, activeImage + 1).replace(/{y}/, images.length));

        if (prevImage >= 0) preloadPrev.src = images[prevImage][0];
        if (nextImage >= 0) preloadNext.src = images[nextImage][0];

        centerWidth = image.offsetWidth;
        centerHeight = image.offsetHeight;
        var top = Math.max(0, middle - (centerHeight / 2));
        if (center.offsetHeight != centerHeight) {
            $(center).animate({height: centerHeight, top: top}, options.resizeDuration, options.resizeEasing);
        }
        if (center.offsetWidth != centerWidth) {
            $(center).animate({width: centerWidth, marginLeft: -centerWidth/2}, options.resizeDuration, options.resizeEasing);
        }
        $(center).queue(function() {
            $(bottomContainer).css({width: centerWidth, top: top + centerHeight, marginLeft: -centerWidth/2, visibility: "hidden", display: ""});
            $(image).css({display: "none", visibility: "", opacity: ""}).fadeIn(options.imageFadeDuration, animateCaption);
        });
    }

    function animateCaption() {
        if (prevImage >= 0) $(prevLink).show();
        if (nextImage >= 0) $(nextLink).show();
        $(bottom).css("marginTop", -bottom.offsetHeight).animate({marginTop: 0}, options.captionAnimationDuration);
        bottomContainer.style.visibility = "";
    }

    function stop() {
        preload.onload = null;
        preload.src = preloadPrev.src = preloadNext.src = activeURL;
        $([center, image, bottom]).stop(true);
        $([prevLink, nextLink, image, bottomContainer]).hide();
    }

    function close() {
        if (activeImage >= 0) {
            stop();
            activeImage = prevImage = nextImage = -1;
            $(center).hide();
            $(overlay).stop().fadeOut(options.overlayFadeDuration, setup);
        }

        return false;
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: If you add the same selector to the livequery (instead of `this`), the grouping problem is fixed, but it is called very often.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing your showNewContent() callback this way...

```
function showNewContent() {
  // Attach slimbox to new content...
  $('#content').find("a[rel^='lightbox']").slimbox({}, null, function(el) {
       return (this == el) || ((this.rel.length > 8) && (this.rel == el.rel));
    }); 
  // ... and then bring up the new stuff.
  $('#content').fadeIn('normal',hideLoader());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<script src="../slimbox-2.05/slimbox2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        jQuery(function ($) {
            $("a[rel^='lightbox']").slimbox({/* Put custom options here */
            }, null, function (el) {
                return (this == el) || ((this.rel.length > 8) && (this.rel == el.rel));
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since livequery is deprecated for a long time, my solution that is working is to use the jQuery function `.each()` like in this example:

```
function refreshSlimbox() {
    $('a[rel^=\'lightbox\']').each(function(){ 
        $('a[rel^=\'lightbox\']').slimbox({/* Put custom options here */}, null, function(el) {
            return (this == el) || ((this.rel.length > 8) && (this.rel == el.rel));
        }), function() {
            //remove slimbox? this is called when elements no longer match
        }
    });
}
```

to refresh i call the `refreshSlimbox()` when ajax is ready