# Jquery tools - live tooltip for Ajax

Tags: jquery, tooltip, jquery-tools

I have a working version of tooltip (jQuery Tools - http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/index.html)  ,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
jQuery('.more_info').each(function(){
   jQuery(this).tooltip({ 
       effect: 'slide',
       offset: [10, 570],
       predelay: 100, 
       position: "bottom left"}).dynamic( { 
        bottom: { 
        direction: 'down', 
        bounce: true 
    } 
    }); 
});
```

});

after ajax is loaded , tooltips not working any more because , script already was loaded , i tried solution from forum http://flowplayer.org/tools/forum/30/37281 , but is not working , or is not implemented correctly

here is code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
jQuery('.more_info').each(function(){
   jQuery(this).not('.tt_init').tooltip({ 
       effect: 'slide',
       offset: [10, 570],
       predelay: 100, 
       position: "bottom left"}).dynamic( { 
        bottom: { 
        direction: 'down', 
        bounce: true 
        } 
    });
    jQuery(this).not('.tt_init').addClass('tt_init'); 
});
```

});

and nothing ... I'm doing something wrong , Thank you for helping ;) , sorry for my bad English

Comment: You do not need an `each` with jquery plugins. This is overkill.

Comment: I'm newbie in Jquery , and what is the better way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same solution as the following:

[livequery not working with groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629508/livequery-not-working-with-groups)

Use the livequery plugin. If tooltip holds for all your pages, it should be refreshed every time. This is were livequery comes in.

Also check this link:

[JQuery slimbox rebind after ajax callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854130/jquery-slimbox-rebind-after-ajax-callback)

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is dynamic content you could try using the [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) jQuery api.

```
jQuery('.more_info').live('mouseover', function(){
    // may need to check here if it already has a tooltip (depending on plugin)
    jQuery(this).tooltip({ 
       effect: 'slide',
       offset: [10, 570],
       predelay: 100, 
       position: "bottom left"}).dynamic( { 
           bottom: { 
           direction: 'down', 
           bounce: true 
       } 
  }); 
});
```

Another solution is to manually activate tooltips for ajax content. something like:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
  $(this).find('.more_info').tooltip({*/...*/});
});
```

Or you could do this for all ajax requests using the [global responders](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/).

Comment: if it would be mouseover, that would be the case, but there is no `live('tooltip')`. So livequery would be a solution.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - tooltip shows when you mouse over, so a `live([tooltip selector]) -> activate tooltip` should do the trick without using livequery. Which is a pretty heavy plugin.