# jQuery tooltip disappears after AJAX DOM update

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, updatepanel, jquery-tooltip

In my layout template , just before closing body tag, I have a Javascript that initializes jQuery tooltips. Here it is (nothing extraordinary):

```
$('.grid-column-header, .small-button, .text-with-second-content').tooltip({ show: { effect: "none"} });
```

Everything works fine until I perform AJAX updates. For instance, an ASP. NET UpdatePanel that replaces a part of my DOM. After DOM is replaced, jQuery tooltip disappears.

Is there a way to address this issue?

p.s. this problem applies to other plugins. Sometimes I get around this problem just by calling pluting initialization code once again after AJAX call.

Comment: This is the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341623/asp-net-updatepanel-in-gridview-jquery-datepicker/3341741#3341741

Comment: I had resolved this problem with this post:

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682181/jquery-tools-live-tooltip-for-ajax>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function InitTooltip(){$('.grid-column-header, .small-button, .text-with-second-content').tooltip({ show: { effect: "none"} });}
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(InitTooltip);
```